# Is "have to" a modal verb?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs, syntax

I have heard people say that "have to" is a modal verb. Other people have told me it is not. Why exactly is "have to" a modal verb? Or why exactly is it not?

I have also heard that it is a periphrastic modal verb. Is a periphrastic modal verb a modal verb?

Comment: [link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have-to?q=have+to)

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by "modal verb." It's just a matter of terminology. Relevant comments by F.E. on one of my ELU Meta posts: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7033/merge-tag-modals-with-modal-verbs#comment26512_7033

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fixed list of modal verbs and semimodals.

Modal verbs: **can, could, may, might, shall, should, will, would, and must.**

Semimodals: **ought + to-infinitive, have + to-infinitive, be able + to-infinitive, dare and need, had better (that is mostly classified as a compound verb), used + to-infinitive or used to + do-insertion.**

While **"have (got) to"** isn't a modal verb, **"have"** is an auxiliary verb along with **"be"** and **"do"**.

**"Have to"** or **"have got to"** (British English) also carries a meaning of something obligatory in the same way modal verbs do:

- I must go to school.
- I should go to school.
- I have to go to school.

The way grammar says it:

**"Have"** is an auxiliary verb. Modal verbs are followed by infinitives without "to". In **"have to"**, **"have"** is the main verb that follows a **to-infinitive**.

- **Have (got) to** can either follow an auxiliary verb or not.

In the Simple Past and Simple Present it doesn't follow an auxiliary verb.

- I have to read.
- She had to play.

In the Future Simple it is preceded with an auxiliary verb "will".

- I will have to go.

In the negative sentences it always follows an auxiliary verb.

- I didn't have to go there. (do)
- I won't have to be there. (will)
- I don't have to sign this. (do)

In the interrogative sentences an auxiliary verb comes first and is followed by a subject, which is followed by **"have to"**.

- Did you have to go to school yesterday? (do)
- Do you have to read this? (do)
- Will you have to be there tomorrow? (will)

> In fact we conjugate **"have to"** in the same way we conjugate any main
>   verb.

---

> **Note**: **"have to"** and **"must"** are both used to express a strong obligation. The difference is that with **"must"** this usually means that some personal circumstance makes the obligation necessary (and the speaker almost certainly agrees with the obligation.) and with **"have to"** this usually means that some external circumstance makes the obligation necessary.

---

> **Extra note**: Remember that in the negative sentences **"do not have to"** suggests that someone is not required to do something while **"must not"** suggests that you are prohibited from doing something.

1. It is a *false assumption* to say that **"have to"** is a modal verb of obligation.
2. It is a *false assumption* to say that **"have to"** is a **"have to + infinitive"**. In fact it is an auxiliary verb "have" plus a to-infinitive.

***However***, it is accepted by some dictionaries and sources to define **"have to"** as a modal verb. ([Oxford Learners Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/have-to), [Perfect English Grammar](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/modal-verbs-of-obligation.html), [Ginger](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/modal-verbs/), [LinguaPress](http://linguapress.com/grammar/modal-obligation.htm), [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/must-have-to-1211255), [Woodward English](http://www.grammar.cl/english/must.htm))

Answer (score 9):

**Have to** is not a modal verb, it is not even an auxiliary verb.
In the **have to** [structure](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modals-have-to-must-not.htm) **have** is a main verb:

Examples:

Declarative sentence:

> I [do] have to go

Questions:

> Do I have to go?

Negatives:

> I don’t have to go.

Here, as we can see, the **have to** structure is used with the auxiliary **do**. This is not something specific to a modal. A modal would never occur next to an auxiliary or to another modal.

> He can have to help find solutions.

Here, we see the occurrence of the **have to** structure next to the modal **can**.

Although we can name this structure [Periphrastic modal](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300051/is-have-to-a-modal-verb) if we wish, I would say that actually it is not a modal verb.

Comment: I think your answer needs a bit more unpacking for learners to be able to understand exactly what you're showing them (i.e. how do those examples show that *have to* isn't a modal verb?)

Answer (score 1):

In a broader sense, *verbs* are generally of two types - *Auxiliary verbs* and *Lexical verbs*.

*Auxiliary Verbs* are further classified into two - *Modal auxiliary verbs* and *Non-Modal Auxiliary Verbs*.

So to know whether *have to* is a modal verb or not, we have to first know whether it's a lexical verb or an auxiliary verb.

**LEXICAL VERB vs AUXILIARY VERBS**

A good device to distinguish an auxiliary verb from other lexical verbs is NICE. It stands for (N)egation, (I)nversion, (C)ode and (E)mphasis.

- NEGATION - (Primary Verb negation)

A lexical verb takes *do* support for negation, generally, but an auxiliary verb doesn't.

> I **don't** *want* it any more. [*want* - A lexical verb, needs *do*-support]
>
> He *is* **not** a thief. [*is* - is an auxiliary verb, and so don't need any *do*-support]

But *have to* behaves little differently in case of negation. For negation, it can take *do*-support, or it can go without it. Both constructions are fine.

> He doesn't have to be that cautious.
>
> We have not to repeat it again.
>
> You know, you have to not be somebody who takes all of their anger.

- INVERSION -

For inversion also, a lexical verb takes *do*-support, but an auxiliary verb doesn't.

> Do you want another drink? [The lexical verb - *want* - takes *do*-support for inversion]
>
> Is he a film star? [The auxiliary verb - *is* - doesn't take *do*-support for inversion]

Let's check how *have to* behaves during INVERSION -

> Do I have to study hard?
>
> I have to study hard -> * Have to I study hard? [INCORRECT]
>
> I have to study hard -> * Have I to study hard? [INCORRECT]

So in this construction, *have to* behaves like a lexical verb.

- CODE -

It's like ellipsis. The Verb Phrase (VP) of a clause is reduced. And the reduced portion is recovered from the context. In the following sentences the reduced or elliptical position is denoted by a "___". An auxiliary verb can take part in such way, but a lexical verb can't.

> I can drive this car, and Bill can ____ too. [The elliptical portion - *drive this car* - is denoted by a "___"]

This sentence is correct because the auxiliary verb - *can* - take part in such constructions.

> I want to drive that car, and my friend wants ___ too. [INCORRECT - because lexical verb - *want* - can't take part in such constructions]

Now let's examine *have to* with such constructions -

> Maybe I'll go over there if I really have to ___. [In the gap we can write *go over there*]

Like an auxiliary verb, *have to* can take part in such constructions.

- EMPHASIS -

The emphasis is on the auxiliary verb, when there is no auxiliary verb we need a dummy *do* for emphasis or stress.

> I never imagined that he could pass the test, but he COULD pass the test. [STRESSED]
>
> I never imagined that he passed the test, but he PASSED the test. [NO STRESS]
>
> I never imagined that he passed the test, but he DID pass the test. [STRESSED]

Now let's examine how *have to* behave in such cases.

> I have to win the race, and I DO have to win the race. [STRESSED]

The verb *have to* needs *do* support for stress. It's a property of a lexical verb.

Apart from NICE, there are other ways to determine whether a verb is an auxiliary verb or a lexical verb.

1. Placement of adverbs
2. Negative inflection and reduced form

   - 1. Placement of adverbs -

Frequency adverbs (like *always, often* etc) and modal adverbs (like *possibly, certainly* etc) generally precedes lexical verbs, and follows auxiliary verbs.

> He is always after money. [*always* follows an auxiliary verb - *is*]
>
> He always wants money. [*always* precedes a lexical verb - *want*]

Now check how *have to* takes such adverbs -

> He always have to ask Charlie.
>
> You have to always evolve.
>
> You have always to talk.

- 2. Negative inflection and reduced form -

Well, like auxiliary verb, *have to* has a reduced form - *haven't to*.

> Some wives earn a lot of money and so their husbands haven't to work.
>
> She said I can't tell you, I haven't to tell you!

So judging from the above, it's clear that *have to* has both the property of a lexical verb and the property of an auxiliary verb. So some grammarians (for example Quirk et el. in A Comprehensive Grammar of English Language) call *have to* a Semi-Auxiliary Verb. Some grammarians don't call it that. For them, *have* is the verb, and it have dual property. It can either be a lexical verb or an auxiliary verb.

So even if it's an auxiliary verb, it's not a modal verb.

[To be continued - Discussion regarding why it's not a modal verb]

Comment: You might want to delete your post while you're editing it! A few points. (A) For some speakers *have* in the *have to* construction, does behave like an auxiliary verb. So these speakers say thing like *Have we to be there tomorrow?* and *We've to be there by 5pm, haven't we*. This is relatively rare, though. (B) We can have subclausal negation where the sentence has positive polarity but an embedded subordinate clause is negated. So the sentence *You have to not respond to his provocations* is grammatical ( - as is *You have to not go there*, although it is clunky). ...

Comment: ... Notice that this sentence has a negative polarity tag showing that the sentence is positive: "You have to not respond, don't you". So the *not* here belongs with *respond* not with *have*. (C) The word *to*  takes part in code constructions - one of the reasons that Pullum and many others believe it's an auxiliary verb: "I have to go there and my friends have to ___ too" (this sentence is grammatical - your example isn't but that's because of *either*, which is a negative polarity item.

Comment: I would think about showing (i) that it doesn't behave like an auxiliary for *most speakers* (ii) that it isn't a *modal* auxiliary for any speakers (iii) that the *to* does not belong with *have* - it belongs with the following verb (i.e. the following VP). But I like the general angle your taking ... :-) [You might want to add that *modal verb* is generally used as a syntactic label, not a semantic one ...]